# Tienen información sobre textura de haralik (entropia, contraste,correlación, energia, homogeneidad)?

Tags: java, android

alguien tiene información de como aplicar textura de haralik (entropia, contraste,correlación, energia, homogeneidad) a una imagen  ?.

Añado código(para que me deje publicar la pegunta- es ecualizacion de histograma con OPENCV);en caso les sirva a alguien:

```
public void EcualizacionHistogramaOPENCV(){
    Mat sourceMat = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, sourceMat);

    Mat destinationMat = new Mat(sourceMat.size(), sourceMat.type());
    Imgproc.cvtColor(sourceMat, sourceMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    Imgproc.equalizeHist(sourceMat, destinationMat);

    Bitmap equalizerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceMat.cols(), sourceMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(destinationMat, equalizerBitmap);

    //show equalized image
    imgviewecualizacion.setImageBitmap(equalizerBitmap);
    GuardarEcualizacion();
}

private Bitmap bitmapFromImageView(){
    return ((BitmapDrawable)imgviewtomarfoto.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
}
```

Comment: Supongo este codigo ya esta modificaco los pixeles es la textura no?, Lo que quieres hacer es combinar esta textura en una foto que este por detras como background. Si es solo mostrar la opcion background del imageview, si es para guardarla en un disposito tendras q combinar las 2 dibujar con un canvas.

Comment: En realidad busco información de como hacer aplicar textura de haralik  a una imagen, el codigo que puse es de ecualizcion de histograma, lo puse para que me deje publicar mi pregunta